# Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 ,ERROR

Tags: react-native

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.71.16.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\AAYUSHMAN PATHAK\OneDrive\Desktop\android app Arpita\sample2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\AAYUSHMAN PATHAK\OneDrive\Desktop\android app Arpita\sample2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\AAYUSHMAN PATHAK\OneDrive\    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\AAYUSHMAN PATHAK\OneDrive\Desktop\android app Arpita\sample2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

HERE I AM TRYING TO RUN THE COMMAND " .\gradlew.bat app:installDebug" IN THE ANDROID FOLDER OF THE PROJECT,AND IT IS SHOWING

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.71.16.
> Required by:
> project :app

NOT GETTING HOW TO CORRECT IT AND MOVE AHEAD OF IT

I HAVE PREVIOUSLY TRIED CHANGING THE GRADLE VERSION IN build.gradle of the project to what it is given  in gradle-wrapper.properties of the android studio,but it did not work ,it is showing the same error again,how to correct it.